# How do I set the policy for users to modify the network state and connections?

Tags: network-manager, policykit

How can I set the permissions for users to make changes to the network connections and state? For instance, how can I allow/disallow users to connect to new wireless networks? How can I allow/disallow users to turn off networking?

Answer (score 12):

**You can create a local policy for one or more users.**

Create the document where the settings will live...

```
touch /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-network-manager.pkla
```

Add one or more policies...

```
[Let foo modify system settings for network]
Identity=unix-user:foo
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes

[Do not allow foo to enable/disable networking]
Identity=unix-user:foo
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.enable-disable-network
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

The key is the `ResultActive` element which can be set to yes, no, auth_admin, or auth_admin_keep where the latter two will require the password of another user with sudo privileges.

The `Action` element defines what action will be allowed/disallowed or require authentication with a password. There are options like `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network` for toggling network as enabled/disabled. You can see more options in the `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy` file, just look for something like `<action id="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network">` and read it's description.

You can also set all values with the `*` wildcard...

```
[Prevent foo from modifying all network states and settings except with admin password]
Identity=unix-user:foo
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=auth_admin_keep
```

This will require a password to make ANY change to network settings or state.

You can do this in a single command that could be included in a script...

```
sudo su -c 'printf "[Prevent foo from modifying all network states and settings]\nIdentity=unix-user:foo\nAction=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*\nResultAny=no\nResultInactive=no\nResultActive=auth_admin" >  /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-network-manager.pkla'
```

References:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/polkit.8.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pklocalauthority.8.html

Comment: `ResultAny=no` has to be set to `yes`, when dealing with e.g. a systemd user service.
`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user to the 'netdev' group.

But I'm not sure if that doesn't give them more rights then intended.

See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Connect_to_wireless_and_ethernet_networks

Answer (score -3):

Linux os is secure, it’s most likely asking for authentication before entering a WiFi login key, I’ve had issues with it too,
All you need to do is when the message appears enter the user password and then you’ll be prompted to enter network key.

There’s no need to go into etc/ or /use or modify any file isn’t the actual file system creating yet another problem.

It’s a security steps, if someone get a hold of your computer once they log out they’ll need your password to access the browser.

If you don’t have the password to get into network then you shouldn’t use that computer.

Comment: I believe the question is asking something different. Case in point, when company notebooks are handed out, employees will need the ability to connect to different networks on their own, but some networks -- such as the public WiFi at McDonald's or Starbucks -- could be "forbidden". This is where a policy works really well to allow people a little flexibility without giving up the farm.

Comment: Your account may be have administrator privilege, If a standard user is trying to add to a new WiFi network then it will ask for admin user password in my experience.